# Understanding java logger - Different output for almost identical code

Tags: java, logging

The first piece of code is doing almost exactly the same thing as the second one. But the hierarchal propagation of Log record is different. Can someone please explain why its happening. Thanks

```
Logger log1 = Logger.getLogger("Test1");
        Logger log2 = Logger.getLogger("Test1.Test2");
        Logger log3 = Logger.getLogger("Test1.Test2.Test3");
        log2.setLevel(Level.WARNING);
        log3.setLevel(Level.INFO);
        log2.addHandler(new ConsoleHandler());
        log3.addHandler(new ConsoleHandler());
        log1.log(Level.INFO, "Message By: {0}",log1.getName());
        log2.log(Level.INFO, "Message By: {0}",log2.getName());
        log3.log(Level.INFO, "Message By: {0}",log3.getName());

OUTPUT: Nov 27, 2014 8:32:51 PM Test main
INFO: Message By: Test1
Nov 27, 2014 8:32:51 PM Test main
INFO: Message By: Test1.Test2.Test3
Nov 27, 2014 8:32:51 PM Test main
INFO: Message By: Test1.Test2.Test3
Nov 27, 2014 8:32:51 PM Test main
INFO: Message By: Test1.Test2.Test3
```

---

```
Logger logger      = Logger.getLogger("d");
        Logger logger1     = Logger.getLogger("d.1");
        Logger logger1_2   = Logger.getLogger("d.1.2");
        logger1  .setLevel(Level.WARNING);
        logger1_2.setLevel(Level.INFO);
        logger     .info("msg:");
        logger1    .info("msg: 1");
        logger1_2  .info("msg: 1.2");
OUTPUT:
Nov 27, 2014 8:33:34 PM Test main
INFO: msg:
Nov 27, 2014 8:33:34 PM Test main
INFO: msg: 1.2
```

Comment: What is the "difference" that you are concerning?

Comment: Your code is not almost identical, and your output matches the differences there are. What is your question?

Comment: How come the two output are different ? Logically I am doing the same thing. The middle logger level is set to Warning. All three are giving INFO's. The lowest logger INFO message should not have propagated to the top as the middle one is set to Warning.

Answer (score 0):

> The lowest logger INFO message should not have propagated to the top as the middle one is set to Warning

That assumption is the source of your confusion.  Record propergation is decsribed in the [java.util.logging.Logger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html) class documentation.  Per the documentation:

> By default, loggers also publish to their parent's Handlers, recursively up the tree.

The child logger is directly logging to the parent handler not the parent logger.  So the level of the parent handler is what comes in to play not the level of the parent logger in this case.